# A good method for conflating queue entries

Tags: java, performance, queue

I have a pool of threads which are fed tasks from a queue. Generally, a small number of threads are able to keep the queue empty. Occasionally, a particularly large burst of events will keep the queue size above zero for some time, but not for long.

My concern is regarding events that are duplicates or carry data that obsoletes previous events. During times of high volume, such events can coexists in the queue for a short period of time. I would like to be able to conflate these so that I can reduce time spent doing wasted work.

What is a good way to conflate such a queue? I could conflate at insertion time by iterating from back to head and searching for a candidate to replace, however this seems too brute-force. If you have code or library recommendations, please keep in mind that I am using Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just implement hashCode() and equals() based on your tasks. Then just remove the task. For example.

```
queue.remove(task);
queue.offer(task);
```

Then you will not have duplicates. Or alternatively.

```
if(!queue.contains(task)) {
   queue.offer(task);
}
```

This will avoid enqueuing the task if its already in the queue.

Comment: The remove() function will start searching from the head of the queue. If it finds a match, it will remove it and I will add the new item at the end, but I need to add the item at the same location. Remove() will also create an ordering problem if there are multiple duplicates on the queue.

Comment: Then don't remove, just check before you add. Notice the two options I provided.

Comment: Whatever I do it modifies the ordering of the queue anyway. I've opted for this solution, but instead of checking contains, I do: isEmpty() ? offer() : remove(), offer(); Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), you can preserve the ordering in which the entries were added to the queue.

When a matching entry arrives, I gather that you want to append some of its data to the original queue entry. In this case, you can either update the hashed object in place, or use [`HashMap.put(key, value)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) to replace the queued item with a new object. (I **think** that this preserves the order of the original item, but I have not tested this.)

Note that your code will need to explicitly synchronize read and write access to the `LinkedHashMap` and the data inside it. You don't want to be updating an item in the queue at the same time that another thread is grabbing it for processing. The easiest way to synchronize is probably by accessing the `LinkedHashMap` through `Collections.synchronizedMap()`.

Answer (score 2):

This conflator seems to do what you are looking for:
https://github.com/GuillaumeArnaud/conflator

Depending on your requirements, the implementation can be changed to merge OR replace the latest event with an existing event, if one exists in the conflation queue.

For eg. for the following, each event is implemented as a "Tick", which defines the merge behaviour.

```
public class Tick implements Message<Tick> {

    private final String ticker;

    public long getInitialQuantity() {
        return initialQuantity;
    }

    private final long initialQuantity;

    public long getCurrentQuantity() {
        return currentQuantity;
    }

    private long currentQuantity;
    private int numberOfMerges;

    public String getTicker() {
        return ticker;
    }

    public Tick(String ticker, long quantity) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
        this.initialQuantity = quantity;
        this.currentQuantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return this.ticker;
    }

    @Override
    public String body() {
        return String.valueOf(currentQuantity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMerged() {
        return this.initialQuantity != this.currentQuantity;
    }

    @Override
    public int mergesCount() {
        return numberOfMerges;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean merge(Tick message) {
        if (this.equals(message)) {
            this.currentQuantity += message.currentQuantity;
            numberOfMerges++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ticker.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof Tick) {
            Tick other = (Tick) obj;
            return this.ticker.equals(other.getTicker());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Test case:

```
public class TickMergeTest {
    MultiValuedMapConflator conflator;

    @Test
    public void two_unmergeable_ticks_should_be_remain_unmergeable() {
        Tick tick1 = new Tick("GOOG", 100L);
        Tick tick2 = new Tick("AAPL", 120L);

        List<Tick> messages = conflator.merge(Lists.newArrayList(tick1, tick2));

        assertNotNull(messages);
        assertEquals(messages.size(), 2);
        assertEquals(Long.valueOf(messages.get(0).body()).longValue(), tick1.getCurrentQuantity());
        assertEquals(Long.valueOf(messages.get(1).body()).longValue(), tick2.getCurrentQuantity());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 1000)
    public void two_mergeable_ticks_should_be_merged() {
        Tick tick1 = new Tick("GOOG", 100L);
        Tick tick2 = new Tick("GOOG", 120L);

        List<Tick> messages = conflator.merge(Lists.newArrayList(tick1, tick2));

        assertNotNull(messages);
        assertEquals(messages.size(), 1);
        assertEquals(Long.valueOf(messages.get(0).body()).longValue(), tick1.getInitialQuantity() + tick2.getInitialQuantity());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 1000)
    public void should_merge_messages_on_same_key() throws InterruptedException {
        // given
        conflator.put(new Tick("GOOG", 100L));
        conflator.put(new Tick("GOOG", 120L));

        // test
        Thread.sleep(300); // waiting the conflation
        Message message = conflator.take();

        // check
        assertNotNull(message);
        assertEquals(Long.valueOf(message.body()).longValue(), 220L);
        assertTrue(message.isMerged());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 1000)
    public void should_not_merge_messages_on_diff_key() throws InterruptedException {
        // given
        conflator.put(new Tick("GOOG", 100L));
        conflator.put(new Tick("AAPL", 120L));

        // test
        Thread.sleep(300); // waiting the conflation
        Message message1 = conflator.take();
        Message message2 = conflator.take();

        // check
        assertNotNull(message1);
        assertNotNull(message2);

        assertEquals(Long.valueOf(message1.body()).longValue(), 100L);
        assertFalse(message1.isMerged());

        assertEquals(Long.valueOf(message2.body()).longValue(), 120L);
        assertFalse(message2.isMerged());

    }
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        conflator = new MultiValuedMapConflator<Tick>(true);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        conflator.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated with context and test cases